# How to prevent the detection of fake GPS?

Tags: smali, mock-location

I found an app that detects Location spoofing and returns a warning screen. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbhuU.jpg
Then I tried to reverse engineer the app and remove the function `isFromMockProvider()`which checks whether the Location data is from a Mock location provider or not. I found these lines of code from a smali file

```
method public onLocationChanged(Landroid/location/Location;)V
.registers 10
.annotation build Landroidx/annotation/RequiresApi;
    api = 0x12
.end annotation

const-string v0, "0"

.line 1
invoke-virtual {p1}, Landroid/location/Location;->isFromMockProvider()Z

move-result v1

const-string v2, "IS_MOCK"

const-string v3, "LIVE_TRACKING_MOCK_LOCATION"

if-eqz v1, :cond_1e

.line 2
new-instance p1, Landroid/content/Intent;

invoke-direct {p1, v3}, Landroid/content/Intent;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V

const-string v0, "false"

.line 3
invoke-virtual {p1, v2, v0}, Landroid/content/Intent;->putExtra(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;

.line 4
invoke-static {p0}, Landroidx/localbroadcastmanager/content/LocalBroadcastManager;->getInstance(Landroid/content/Context;)Landroidx/localbroadcastmanager/content/LocalBroadcastManager;

move-result-object v0

invoke-virtual {v0, p1}, Landroidx/localbroadcastmanager/content/LocalBroadcastManager;->sendBroadcast(Landroid/content/Intent;)Z

return-void

.line 5
:cond_1e
new-instance v1, Landroid/content/Intent;

invoke-direct {v1, v3}, Landroid/content/Intent;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V

const-string v3, "false"
```

what changes have to be made here to prevent the detection of mock location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calls

```
invoke-virtual {p1}, Landroid/location/Location;->isFromMockProvider()Z
move-result v1
```

returns `1` (true) if a mock provider is used and `0` otherwise. The result is stored in `v1`.

Later the value is used for a conditional branch in

```
if-eqz v1, :cond_1e   // if v1==0 GOTO cond_1e
```

So only if there is no mock provider used (v1=0) it jumps to a special code part. Otherwise it continues with a code part that handles the mock location which is most likely what you don't want.

So you have to tweak that check and for doing so you have two possibilities:

1. Overwrite `v1` with 0 before the check, e.g. via the command `const/4 v1, 0x0`
2. Replace the conditional branch `if-eqz v1, :cond_1e` with a non-conditional `goto :cond_1e` so it doesn't matter what value `v1` has.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @robert.

"1. Overwrite v1 with 0 before the check, e.g. via the command const/4 v1, 0x0"

this one worked for me.